# How do you iterate a function in gdb with various inputs until you get a successful return value

Tags: assembly, gdb

I am working on a bomb project, meaning that I need to figure out the correct inputs for a program, but I don't have access to the original code.

Currently, I am trying to figure out how to get a function called `func4` to output a 1. `func4` only takes in a single integer argument. I have examined the assembly instructions for this function, but it looks like `func4` is some kind of hash function, which would make it very painful to try and backtrack to the correct input.

Is there some way I can run `func4` repeatedly while I'm using gdb? I would like to iterate the function with inputs 1240, 1241, 1242, and so on until I reach a certain break point (meaning that the input was correct).

Comment: It *might* help to put a breakpoint on the `explode_bomb` function so you can script GDB to see if it stopped there.  In your case, "failure" is indicated by calling that, not by the function's return value.

Comment: @PeterCordes I am doing that currently. I don't have access to the program atm, but I am afraid that manually changing the input is going to be too slow because the conditions to return a 1 seem very constrictive.

Comment: But just as a general tip, it's very unlikely that your instructor assigned a bomb with a truly one-way hash function that can't be turned into an equation and solved for the input.  The point of a bomb lab is that they *can* be reverse-engineered once you understand the logic they implement, and that's supposed to be the challenge.  A SHA1 or even CRC32 or something would completely defeat the purpose, or be a a cryptography assignment, not just reverse-engineering.

Comment: GDB's command language includes enough scripting capability to support loops!  I'm suggesting that you set a breakpoint before looping on `set tmp = call func4(i)` or something (if that's the right syntax).  It's hopefully possible for your loop to use GDB commands to check for hitting a breakpoint instead of returning.  Or if the function returns 0 or 1 and printing is just a side effect, my suggestion is probably not helpful.  Anyway, of course you wouldn't manually feed it inputs, that's not what I said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

For illustration purpose, let's assume that the program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int hash(unsigned int x) {
  return ((x << 20) % 191) | (x % 57);
}

int main()
{
  int j = 1;
  printf("%d: %d\n", j, hash(j));
  return 0;
}
```

I compile it with `gcc -O3 -fno-inline t.c`, and observe this disassembly in GDB:

```
gdb -q ./a.out
Reading symbols from ./a.out...

(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x1050
Starting program: /tmp/a.out

Temporary breakpoint 1, 0x0000555555555050 in main ()
(gdb) disas hash
Dump of assembler code for function hash:
   0x0000555555555170 <+0>: mov    %edi,%ecx
   0x0000555555555172 <+2>: mov    $0xab8f69e3,%edx
   0x0000555555555177 <+7>: shl    $0x14,%ecx
   0x000055555555517a <+10>:    mov    %ecx,%eax
   0x000055555555517c <+12>:    mul    %edx
   0x000055555555517e <+14>:    mov    %edi,%eax
   0x0000555555555180 <+16>:    shr    $0x7,%edx
   0x0000555555555183 <+19>:    imul   $0xbf,%edx,%edx
   0x0000555555555189 <+25>:    sub    %edx,%ecx
   0x000055555555518b <+27>:    mov    $0x1f7047dd,%edx
   0x0000555555555190 <+32>:    mul    %edx
   0x0000555555555192 <+34>:    mov    %edi,%eax
   0x0000555555555194 <+36>:    sub    %edx,%eax
   0x0000555555555196 <+38>:    shr    %eax
   0x0000555555555198 <+40>:    add    %eax,%edx
   0x000055555555519a <+42>:    mov    %ecx,%eax
   0x000055555555519c <+44>:    shr    $0x5,%edx
   0x000055555555519f <+47>:    imul   $0x39,%edx,%edx
   0x00005555555551a2 <+50>:    sub    %edx,%edi
   0x00005555555551a4 <+52>:    or     %edi,%eax
   0x00005555555551a6 <+54>:    retq
End of assembler dump.
```

Let's also assume that the return value I am looking for is `125`.

The first step is to set a conditional breakpoint on the `retq` instruction:

```
(gdb) b *0x00005555555551a6 if $rax == 125
Breakpoint 2 at 0x5555555551a6
```

Now let's call `hash()` in a loop:

```
set $j = 1240
while $j < 1260
> call (int)hash($j++)
> end
$1 = 63
$2 = 47
$3 = 189
$4 = 174
$5 = 191
$6 = 190
$7 = 177
$8 = 114
$9 = 119
$10 = 118

Breakpoint 2, 0x00005555555551a6 in hash ()
The program being debugged stopped while in a function called from GDB.
Evaluation of the expression containing the function
(hash) will be abandoned.
When the function is done executing, GDB will silently stop.
(gdb) p $j
$11 = 1251
```

So, calling `hash(1250)` produces the desired value.

QED.

Comment: Looks good! I'll accept your answer once I am able to test it out for myself tomorrow.